# achartengine: adding values to CategorySeries mystery

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine

could you please suggest something!

the problem:

i am using achartengine library ([achartengine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)) to draw a pie chart in my android app:

the problem - it works fine for emulator but doesn't work on real phones.
As i found out it (a real phone) thinks that the values are all zeros.
I logged the values in the application right before adding to the series and after as the series elements - they are not zeros.
i've done everything that should be done - exported library achartengine-1.1.0.jar and so on, it works fine apart from that

details:

i pass Integer arrayList to my class (that would be the data for the pie chart)
then i convert it to double because add method accepts double values:

[**Add**](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/CategorySeries.html#add%28double%29)

```
add

public void add(java.lang.String category,
            double value)
Adds a new value to the series.
Parameters:
category - the category
value - the new value
```

that's my class that draw pie chart

```java
public class piegraph {

public Intent getIntent(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {

    double val1 = arraylist.get(0).doubleValue();
    double val2 = arraylist.get(1).doubleValue();
    double val3 = arraylist.get(2).doubleValue();
    double val4 = arraylist.get(3).doubleValue();
    double val5 = arraylist.get(4).doubleValue();
    double val6 = arraylist.get(5).doubleValue();


    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Pie iGraph");


    // the way it doesn't work on a phone:

    series.add("6A", val1);
    series.add("6B", val2);
    series.add("6C", val3);
    series.add("7A", val4);
    series.add("7B", val5);
    series.add("7C", val6);


    // the way it works on a phone:

 /*
    series.add("6A", 2);
    series.add("6B", 3);
    series.add("6C", 4);
    series.add("7A", 6);
    series.add("7B", 3);
    series.add("7C", 3); */

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN, Color.LTGRAY };

    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color : colors) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    renderer.setChartTitle("This month");
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(7);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, series, renderer, "Pie");
    return intent;
    }
}
```

and i call it and pass the array list like this:

```java
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnGra:

    ArrayList<Integer> arra = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        arra.add(sum_6a);
        arra.add(sum_6b);
        arra.add(sum_6c);
        arra.add(sum_7a);
        arra.add(sum_7b);
        arra.add(sum_7c);


    piegraph pie = new piegraph();
    Intent lineIntent = pie.getIntent(this, arra);
    startActivity(lineIntent);

    break;

    }
}
```

so i don't really have an idea what could be wrong, tested on two phones, Android 2.3.6, Target version is 2.3.3

thanks!

Comment: Which are the values for val1,...?

Comment: it's ex-Integer, now double, specifically here: 8.0, see, i pass ArrayList of Integer values and after that make them double to fit the requirements of CategorySeries instance.

Comment: Just pass ints and you will be good.

Comment: i tried, it works for emulator either they are ints or doubles, but on a real phones - no data, no diargamm, that's the main question